# fail to keep order for csv columns using csv reader library (tototoshi)

Tags: java, scala, csv

I can't understand why my output file is losing its order.

I'm uploading a csv file with headers (`key1 | key2 | key3`). Then, I use a `CsvDataReader` to iterate over the headers (`scala.Iterator[Map[String, String]]`). I'm mapping this iterator because I want to add values to the csv file, I create a new file for the output but the output has a different order than the original file... At first, it is:

`key1 key2 key3` and after the mapping I expect to see `key1 key2 key3 key4`

but the result is instead:

`key3 key1 key4 key2`

Why is that ?

this is my code:

```
val csvFile = new File(Crypto.decryptAES(request.fileId))
    if (csvFile.exists()) {

      val csvDataReader = new CsvDataReader(csvFile)

      val resultLines = csvDataReader.iteratorWithHeaders.map(row => {
        row ++ Map("key4" -> "val4", "key5" -> "val5")

      }).toList

      val headerOfFile = resultLines.head.keys.toList

      val outputFile = File.createTempFile("output-", ".csv")

      val csvDataWriter = new CsvDataWriter(outputFile,true)
      csvDataWriter.writeHeaders(headerOfFile)

      resultLines foreach {csvDataWriter.write(_,headerOfFile)}
      csvDataReader.close()
      csvDataWriter.close()
```

Comment: It'd be cool to know where your classes come from... if they contain a bug that may be relevant, don't you think so ?

Comment: @Dici which classes? I shared the piece of code that contain the bug and everything there is straight forward csv reader library finctions

Answer (score 0):

The default map returned when using `Map` in Scala is `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`, which is unordered. `row ++ Map(...)` also returns a `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`, therefore it comes unordered.

Looking at the API, you have no other choice than calling `readNext` repeatedly.

```
def appendList[T](list: List[T], toAppend: Seq[T]) = new ListBuffer[T]() ++= list ++= toAppend

val csvFile = new File(Crypto.decryptAES(request.fileId))
if (csvFile.exists()) {
  val csvDataReader = new CsvDataReader(csvFile)

  val headers = csvDataReader.readNext().getOrElse(Nil)
  val newHeaders = appendList(headers, List("key4", "key5"))

  val outputFile = File.createTempFile("output-", ".csv")

  val csvDataWriter = new CsvDataWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile)))

  csvDataReader.iterator.foreach {csvDataWriter.writeRow(appendList(_, List("value4", "value5"))}

  csvDataReader.close()
  csvDataWriter.close()
```

This answer is based on the current version on the library(https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv, commit 715e726), which is apparently not the on you're using.

Comment: how can implement it with LinkedHashMap, assuming it does return ordered map? resultLines returns  `scala.List[Map[String, String]]`

Comment: I'm looking at the code right now, nothing is made to guarantee the order in this method.